# Abstract class A cannot instantiate new instances of abstract class B

Tags: typescript

I'd like to set up a structure where I can create new classes that extend from ClassReturner and TheClass in the code below, but I'm getting an error.

```
abstract class ClassReturner <TClass extends TheClass> {
    private returningClass : TClass;

    constructor ( r : TClass ){
        this.returningClass = r;
    }

    public getAnotherClass (){
        //ERROR BELOW: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
        return new this.returningClass("John Doe");

    }
}

abstract class TheClass {
    private whoiam: string;

    constructor ( w : string ){
        this.whoiam = w;
    }

}
```

Why is this not allowed? Shouldn't the fact that `TClass` extends `TheClass` confirm that it has a constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `returningClass: TClass` is an instance of a class that extends `TheClass`.
To have the ctor you need: `{ new (name: string): TheClass }`.

So this should work for you:

```
abstract class TheClass {
    private whoiam: string;

    constructor(w: string) {
        this.whoiam = w;
    }
}

interface TheClassConstructor<T extends TheClass> {
    new(name: string): T;
}

abstract class ClassReturner<TClass extends TheClass> {
    private returningClass: TheClassConstructor<TClass>;

    constructor(r: TheClassConstructor<TClass>) {
        this.returningClass = r;
    }

    public getAnotherClass() {
        return new this.returningClass("John Doe");
    }
}
```

[Code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20TheClass%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20whoiam%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%20(w%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.whoiam%20%3D%20w%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20TheClassConstructor%3CT%20extends%20TheClass%3E%20%7B%0A%09new(name%3A%20string)%3A%20T%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aabstract%20class%20ClassReturner%20%3CTClass%20extends%20TheClass%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20returningClass%3A%20TheClassConstructor%3CTClass%3E%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(r%20%3A%20TheClassConstructor%3CTClass%3E)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.returningClass%20%3D%20r%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getAnotherClass()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20this.returningClass(%22John%20Doe%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)